# Angular JS directive not updating scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple directive in angularJs which accepts some config options via attributes, but if the attributes are not set, I want to set default values for the attributes.

Here's how I describe my scope:

```
scope :  {
            classes: '@',
            progress: '@'
         }
```

These attribs are displayed in the view in the following way:

```
<div class="{{classes}}">
    <div style="width: {{progress}}%;" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

In the link function, I try to set the default values in this way:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs)
        {
           console.log( scope.classes, scope.progress );
           if (typeof scope.classes === 'undefined')
               scope.classes = 'progress progress-warning';

           if (typeof scope.progress === 'undefined')
               scope.progress = 99;
           console.log( scope.classes, scope.progress );
        }
```

Here's the console output:

```
undefined undefined
progress progress-warning 99
```

So, it appears that in the scope the value is being set correctly. However in the actual html output, the attributes are not being rendered. Here's the resulting HTML:

```
<div class="">
    <div class="bar" style="width: %;"></div>
</div>
```

However if I supply these attributes inline when calling the attribute from html, e.g:

```
<my-directive data-progress="60" data-classes="progress" />
```

then it shows up fine:

```
<div class="progress" data-progress="60" data-classes="progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

My question is, when I just call `<my-directive />`, why does it not set the default values of progress and classes as its supposed to, from the link function? (And despite showing in console that it did)

Comment: Did you try to use scope.$apply(); ? If you can, post a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: you dont need to do `scope.$apply()`

Comment: can you post the full directive?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan I get the `digest already in progress` if I put the code within the link function inside scope.$apply

Comment: Ok my bad, I didn't see that you are changing on the link function.

Comment: @ClickUpvote try removing the replace: true or maybe transclude the template, your default should be setting i usually use a ternary operator its easier to read and cleaner for defaults IMO

Comment: @DavidChase That's a pain in the ass. I'll just supply a default value for the attributes when calling the directive :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.classes = attrs.classes || 'progress progress-warning';
    scope.progress = attrs.progress || 99;
}
```

And you can ditch the `scope :  { classes: '@', progress: '@' }` part of the directive.

I see you're having some hard time writing your directive. Check out [this one](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/src/ng-tags-input.js) I've implemented recently. Perhaps it'll help you wrap up yours.

Comment: fantastic. thanks. The directive I asked previous questions about works fine now, this is just for other directives.

Comment: How come I don't get an undefined error on `attrs.progress` when I do `attrs.progress || 99`?

Comment: This statement check if the variable is `null` or `undefined`, if true, assign the second value.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan Interesting, I thought `typeof` was necessary to check that. Does it work ok in IE too or only in firefox / chrome?

Comment: Actually it checks for anything that evaluates to `false`, and in Javascript, many things do that (null and undefined included). It works for non-boolean values only, for obvious reasons.

Comment: It works in all browsers, but you need to keep in mind that 0 and boolean values will break it. In fact, I've just realized you may run into trouble if 0 is a valid value for `progress`. Can you see why?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (typeof scope.progress === 'undefined') {
       attrs.$set('progress', 99);
}
```

And set:

```
<div class="bar" style="width: {{progress}}%;"></div>
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HkZNUsFIM1DQ8koJVmUx?p=preview). It will set `99` if `data-progress` is not declared or if is `data-progress=""`

Comment: This is the output when I try this: `<div class="" data-ng-hide="hide" classes="progress progress-warning" progress="99">
<div class="bar" style="width: %;"></div>
</div>`

Comment: @ClickUpvote I've updated the plunker to see the div width when I change the value. In this case, I insert {{progress}} into width declaration.  http://plnkr.co/edit/HkZNUsFIM1DQ8koJVmUx?p=preview
Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: you are already providing the progress when you include the directive. you're doing `<my-directive progress="50"  data-classes="progress">`. If I do this, it works for me too, however what I want is to simply do `<my-directive />` and have it set `progress` and `classes` with some default values in that case

Comment: @ClickUpvote but it also works if you remove the attributes... I've removed now and works with the default values... can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

change your scope to

```
scope: {
  ngModel: '@'
}
```

Comment: That works, however the problem is, now if I try to specify the attributes within the tag, e.g `<my-directive data-progress="40" />` that has no effect, and it remains stuck on progress as 99 which is the default value when no value is given